# What is the order of growth of $\prod_{k=2}^{n}logk$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

What is the growth order (Theta) of
$$\sum_{k=3}^{n}\log(\log k)$$
I tried to use logarithm rules and was stuck at
$$\prod_{k=3}^{n}\log k$$
I could only get an upper bound of $O(n\log (\log n))$ on the whole running time.

Comment: Are you calculating the bound of the runtime of the Sieve for primes? Then I suggest you look this up - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-is-the-time-complexity-of-sieve-of-eratosthenes-is-nloglogn/

Comment: @IshraaqParvez No, it is just a part of homework... But I will try to look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where trying to be too clever is counterproductive.

For practical purposes I'd just call it $O(n\log \log n)$ and worry no more.

However, it is also $\Omega(n\log\log n)$: Since $\log \log n$ grows so slowly, *most* of the $\log \log k$ terms are effectively the same as $\log \log n$ -- the very few ones at the beginning that are appreciably smaller have no asymptotic effect.

To make this intuition into an actual proof, let's guess that when $n$ is large enough we'll have $ \log\log k \ge \frac12 \log\log n$ when $k\ge \frac12 n$, and therefore your sum is at least $\frac14 n\log\log n$.

Finding out whether this is true requires solving
$$ \log\log\frac12n \ge \frac 12 \log \log n $$
and a bit of algebra tells us that $n\ge 8$ is certainly large enough.

Comment: In fact, $n\log\log n$ is a much better than asymptotic approximation: The absolute difference $n\log_2\log_2 n - \sum_{k=2}^n \log_2\log_2 k$ grows slower than linearly. The growth is that of the [logarithmic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function) times $\ln(2)^{−2}$, so the difference is roughly 2.08 times the number of primes less than $n$ -- which is not particularly useful to know from an algorithmic point of view, but interesting!